# AWS SNS Filtering based on the Message Body

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Sample message looks like below:

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "23456f-9cca-8f1a-5746363",
  "Message" : "{\"Records\":[{\"eventVersion\":\"2.1\",\"eventSource\":\"aws:s3\"}, {\"key\":\"AWSLogs/12345678/elasticloadbalancing/us-east-1/2023/11/29/rohithmn-1234.k8s-roh-12345678.fsdkjfhwe5639.log.gz\",\"size\":746}]}",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1"
}
```

Now in my SNS Subscription filter policy i would like use **"Message Body"** for filtering only message where it has "rohithmn-1234" in the message key.
What is the JSON filter for this?

I went through https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/ this but it has only **prefix** based filtering.

In my case i would to filter the message if the message Key has **"rohithmn-1234"** string present in it. Meaning send only those messages that has **"rohithmn-1234"**.

Comment: I do not see **rohithmn-1234** in the message payload you have shared, so please share the right message. For the string matching, you can look through: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/string-value-matching.html#string-exact-matching

Comment: I have updated the message body. But intention was if there no matching string it should not pass this/discard this. @ArpitJain

Answer (score 0):

Here for custom message which you are finding you cannot have it. SNS will only share the base JSON payload only. You can have only "Message" as the Email/Slack.

What you can do is, use lambda in between for the sending data

By lambda you can customize your message payload and then send it to your Slack or Email destination. You can find many solution on web for this.

[image]

Good luck, Do leave comment if you need anything.
Happy clouding!!